# Print text after 7th occurrence of delimiter in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have text file that follows this format:

```
    name   loc  -   u   q1:a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h   q2:i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p
```

For each line, I want to extract the text after the 7th occurrence of "|" for each "q" in that line.  In other words, I want to print something like this:

```
            q1    q2
    name    h     p
```

Is there a way I can do this with awk or grep without a loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there an upper limit to the number of `q`s in a line? If there's no limit, you'll need to use a loop. Other utilities may be able to do it without a loop.

Comment: Question is open ended.  From [Help Center>Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it". Even if its not homework you should at least make an attempt at it using awk before asking.

Comment: There is an upper limit to the number of qs in a line, but there is no lower limit.  This is not a hw question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the whitespace between fields are tabs. Since you are using q1 and q2 as headers, I guess they appear set on each line.
First you need to cut out the second, third and fourth field. `cut` is easy here.
For each remaining field you need the same `sed`-operation. Something like

```
echo "name      loc     -       u       q1:a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h      q2:i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p"  | cut -f1,5- |
sed 's/[^\t]*:\([^|]*|\)\{7\}/ /g'
```

Comment: If I wanted to extract the text after the 3rd "|" only, is there a way I could adapt this sed argument?  sed 's/[^\t]*:\([^|]*|\)\{3\}/ /g' returns 'd|e|f|g|h'  Thanks again.

Comment: Try something like `sed -r 's/[^\t]*:([^|]*\|){3}([^|]*)(\|[^|\t]*){4}/\2 /g'`, where the option -r makes some backslashes unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution -

> Input

```
  vipin@kali:~$ cat kk.txt
    q1:a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h   q2:i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p
```

> Output

```
vipin@kali:~$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":|\|| "} {print $2,$12,$23} END {print $1,$20,$31}' OFS="\t" kk.txt
        q1      q2
name    h       p
```

> Explanation

We need to use multiple field seperator `:`, `[Space]`,`|` to divide the columns and the print required output.